My virtual box linux got stuck and also not showing cursor
In my virtual box Linux system when I enter the sudo service sysstat restart command it goes to restart phase but it's been 30 mins now and there will no response it's done or not after this issue of getting stuck another issue came back that is cursor is showing from virtual box to our main system but not working how can i resolve this please give a suitable / proper way to fix it .
